# Run `multiprocessing.Pool.initialize` on a method of the forked class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

```py
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

class A:
  def initialize(self):
    print('initialize', self, os.getpid())

  def run(self):
    print('run       ', self, os.getpid())

a = A()
print('root      ', a, os.getpid())

with Pool(1, initializer=a.initialize) as pool:
  pool.apply(a.run)
```

Out:

```
root       <__main__.A object at 0x7b644c0af1c0> 386
initialize <__main__.A object at 0x7b644c0af1c0> 3264
run        <__main__.A object at 0x7b644c0ae080> 3264
```

I want to initialize the forked process of a `Pool`, in particular to occupy a significant amount of memory that the the parent doesn't need. However, it seems like `a.initialize` runs on the parent's `a` within the child process, which would confuse me because `a` isn't or shouldn't be in shared memory?

How can I adapt the fork of `a` once during `Pool` initialization, such that `a.run` applies on these changes.

EDIT: elegant ways to share information between `pool.apply`s other than global variables are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `self` is just passed as a regular argument, which is copied to the forked process each time `pool.apply` is called. I think the only way to share information between `initialize` and `run` is via global variables. The good news is that these only exist in a forked process and hence are 'somewhat removed' from interfering with module behavior in the parent process.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

class A:
  def initialize(self):
    globals()['worker'] = type(self)()
    print('initialize', globals()['worker'])

  def run(self):
    global worker
    worker.apply()
    
  
  def apply(self):
    print('apply     ', worker)

a = A()

with Pool(1, initializer=a.initialize) as pool:
  pool.apply(a.run)
```

Out:

```
initialize <__main__.A object at 0x7b644c0a77c0>
apply      <__main__.A object at 0x7b644c0a77c0>
```